# Compare Dates from Two Different Region Formats

Tags: delphi, datetime

I have an XML file that stored a date that is in a US date format (M/d/YYYY). In my application, I need to compare that date against the current date using `DaysBetween`. After reading the text value from the XML as a `string`, I try using `StrUtils.StrToDateTime(string)` on it.

This works when the PC is also operating with a US date format. But when I change this to a format that has a different arrangement of the date components like English (New Zealand) which is d/MM/yyyy, the `StrToDateTime' line errors out in my application saying something like:

'6/13/2015' is not a valid date and time.

With that date being what was read from the XML file.

Is there an intelligent way to use `StrToDateTime` and `DaysBetween` to compare a US formatted date (will always be this) with a different kind of date format (should work for any Windows locale)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overloaded [`function StrToDateTime(const S: string; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime;`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToDateTime), which takes a specified `TFormatSetting` as input.

Populate the [`TFormatSetting`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.Create) record according to your US locale setting.

Example:

```
myUSLocale := TFormatSettings.Create('en-US');
```